# how to delete the colums which colSum less than 5000 in a dataset

Tags: r

```
head(otu)
```

| ePA1_lib1 | ePA2_lib1 | ePA3_lib1 | ePA4_lib1 | ePA5_lib1 | ePA6_lib1 | ePA7_lib1 | ePA8_lib1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ASV_1 | 20 | 17 | 26 | 11 | 14 | 36 | 33 |
| ASV_2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ASV_3 | 1 | 5 | 13 | 62 | 68 | 163 | 231 |

I mean, if the `sum` of `ePA1_lib1` in every ASV is less than 5000, then I would like to delete the sample `ePA1_lib1`.

Comment: What do you mean with the sum of `ePA1_lib1`? As this is a character column

Comment: The format may be wrong, the location of  ePA1_lib1 should actually be ASV_ID

Answer (score 1):

There are lot of ways to select columns that sum more than 5000.

```
##Base R
#1.
df[colSums(df) > 5000]
#2.
Filter(function(x) sum(x) > 5000, df)
#3.
df[sapply(df, sum) > 5000]

##Using packages
library(dplyr)
#4.
df %>% select(where(~sum(.) > 5000))
#5.
purrr::keep(df, ~sum(.x) > 5000)
#6.
purrr::discard(df, ~sum(.x) <= 5000)
```

Comment: thanks, I slao found another way.                                                                            
library(rtk)                                                                                                  data.rarefied<-rtk(input=x, depth=5000, margin=2, tmpdir=NULL, repeats=100, ReturnMatrix=1)